# Animating child objects via parent object animator in script

Tags: unity, animation

I'm using unity 5

I'm trying to animate multiple child objects via a parent object. The animation worked in the animation view but would not work when I tried to preview the game. In the script I use the code:

```
ParentObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("intro");
```

to play the animation. A similar line of code worked when playing a singular object, not sure what's going wrong now, any sugestions?

Comment: Can you show your animator window?

Comment: I got the animation to work by setting the update mode to normal in Start(). I have two animations that should be running and only one will run. I assume this has something to do with both animator components having animations on their respective base layers...is that right....one animation acts on the parent (which animates all the children), the other acts on a single child object..

Comment: Can you show us the rest of how you've set this up - your hierarchy of objects, the inspector for the object the animation is playing on, and (if applicable) the animation controller graph if you're using an Animator component rather than an Animation component?

Comment: animatOR and animatION are two different things. The code line you show plays an animatOR state from the corresponding animator component? You have more than one animator?

Comment: @DMGregory, all the child objects are shown in the animation window. the parent is an empty game object.

Comment: @Nikaas, sorry i misread the first comment. I do have more than one animator. The parent has its animator component and the children have theirs. In order to get the animations to play when necessary I switch back and forth between empty and non-empty states that can be found in the animator.

Comment: Your answers are inconsistent. You told me the parent is an empty GameObject, then told Niklaas the parent has an Animator component (ie. not empty). This is why I'm asking you to show us this information, so that we don't get mixed messages or misinterpretations.

Comment: @DMGregory i consider an empty game object as something that doesn't show up on the screen when playing the game. did I use that term incorrectly...I'm still learning....sry

Comment: By that definition, all sorts of very significant objects like trigger volumes, effectors, and custom managers would all get lumped together as "empty" — which doesn't seem like a good way to describe their behaviour. You'll notice that the Unity editor only ever applies this term to a GameObject with *no* components attached to it (except the Transform, which isn't really removable) A good rule of thumb: if someone asks to see something, assume they actually really truly do need to see it. Do not assume that the details are irrelevant.

Comment: if you're curious about the play layer in the animator window, it's an empty layer...at least for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, I'm somewhat of a neophyte when it comes to unity. But the solution that worked for me is switching the animator components for the parent and child objects on when I need them the animations to play and off when I didn't. It's like unity can only work with one animator component at a time...but hey whatever works right?